# I cannot toggle my boolean value in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am working on an anime project. My problem is that when I click the input, I want to bring it to the forefront. So, I used "webkitRequestFullscreen()", but I cannot toggle my boolean to true in order to make it. I looked for some solutions, but I guess, the version I use for Redux is different from theirs and I didn't understand them.

Here is my initial state and reducer function:

```
const initialState = {
  items: [],
  fullScreen: false,
}
reducers: {
    toggleInputScreen: (state, action) => {
      const id = action.payload
      state.fullScreen = !state.fullScreen
    },
  },
```

The main component:

```
let activeFullScreen = useSelector((state) => state.anime.fullScreen)
  // console.log(activeFullScreen)

  if (activeFullScreen) {
    return inputRef.current.webkitRequestFullscreen()
  }
<div
    className="input-container"
    onClick={() => dispatch(toggleInputScreen())}
    id="input-div">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search..." ref={inputRef} />
</div>
```

I know the reducer function is a total disaster. How can I toggle the fullScreen boolean when I click the input? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably the reducer function.

In Redux, the state is **immutable**, which means you **never modify the state**, instead, create a new copy. Another mistake is, that you have to return the new state in the reducer function.

> Reducers are functions that take the current `state` and an `action` as arguments, and return a new `state` result. [...] They are not allowed to modify the existing `state`. Instead, they must make immutable updates, by copying the existing `state` and making changes to the copied values. - [redux guide](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers#writing-reducers)

You can solve your problem by following the just appointed rules:

```
toggleInputScreen: (state, action) => {
  const id = action.payload
  //create and return a new object, which is the new state
  return {
    items: state.items,
    fullScreen: !state.fullScreen,
  }
}
```

If the state is an object and grows in size, you can use the `Object.assign()` method to create a copy of the object and change values of it easily. Check it out [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign?retiredLocale=de) and [here](https://redux.js.org/usage/using-object-spread-operator). For redux you would use the following schema: `Object.assign({}, state, changes)`. In you case, that would look like this:

```
toggleInputScreen: (state, action) => {
  const id = action.payload
  //create and return a new object, which is the new state
  return Object.assign({}, state, { fullscreen: !state.fullscreen }); 
}
```